# How to create a table which gives a list of servers in one row and the count of it in another row using kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

How to create a table which gives a list of servers in one column and the count of it in another column using kusto. I want 7 in one column and the list in another column, Is this possible using kusto

7       SRV-SEF-MOVAV01
        SRV-SEF-MOVAV02
        SRV-SEF-MOVAV03
        SRV-SEF-MOVAV04
        SRV-SEF-MOVAV05
        SRV-SEF-MOVAV06
        SRV-SEF-MOVAV08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat challenging to understand how your input data set looks like based on the description in your original message.

that said, the following could give you a direction:

```
datatable(value:string)
[
    'SRV-SEF-MOVAV01',
    'SRV-SEF-MOVAV02',
    'SRV-SEF-MOVAV03',
    'SRV-SEF-MOVAV04',
    'SRV-SEF-MOVAV05',
    'SRV-SEF-MOVAV06',
    'SRV-SEF-MOVAV08',
]
| summarize count(), make_list(value)
```

this returns the following table:

```
| count_ | list_value                                                                    
|--------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 7      | ["SRV-SEF-MOVAV01","SRV-SEF-MOVAV02","SRV-SEF-MOVAV03","SRV-SEF-MOVAV04","SRV-SEF-MOVAV05","SRV-SEF-MOVAV06","SRV-SEF-MOVAV08"]
```